# Applicative implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a type show as below:

```
newtype WarningAccumulator w a = WarningAccumulator (a,[w])
   deriving (Show,Eq)
```

And then I have a functor and applicative like below:

```
instance Functor (WarningAccumulator w) where
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> WarningAccumulator w a -> WarningAccumulator w b
   fmap f (WarningAccumulator (value, list)) = WarningAccumulator(f value, list)

instance Applicative (WarningAccumulator w) where
   pure :: a -> WarningAccumulator w a
   pure a = WarningAccumulator (a,[])
   (<*>) :: WarningAccumulator w (a -> b) -> WarningAccumulator w a -> WarningAccumulator w b
   (<*>) (WarningAccumulator (empty, f)) (WarningAccumulator (value, list)) = 
      WarningAccumulator (f value, list)
```

Now it gives me an error:

```
The function ‘f’ is applied to one value argument,
    but its type ‘[w]’ has none
  In the expression: f value
  In the first argument of ‘WarningAccumulator’, namely
    ‘(f value, list)’
```

Which I do not understand. Can you explain this to me and then help me fix this issue?

Comment: Also note that `empty`, used as in the snippet above, is just a variable name like `x` -- it can take any value. I don't know if you assumed it to hold any special value instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` has the type `[w]`, which is not the type of a function, so you cannot apply `value` to it. You probably mean this instead:

```hs
-- (empty, f) changed to (f, empty)
(<*>) (WarningAccumulator (f, empty)) (WarningAccumulator (value, list)) = 
   WarningAccumulator (f value, list)
```

However, this instance of `Applicative` is not lawful: it doesn’t satisfy the interchange law

```hs
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

For example:

```hs
u :: WarningAccumulator String (Int -> Int)
u = WarningAccumulator ((+1), ["warning"])

y :: Int
y = 2
```

`u <*> pure y == WarningAccumulator (3, [])` whereas `pure ($ y) <*> u == WarningAccumulator (3, ["warning"])`.

You probably want to concatenate the warnings instead of discarding what you’ve named `empty` (which may not be empty):

```hs
(<*>) (WarningAccumulator (f, xs)) (WarningAccumulator (value, ys)) = 
   WarningAccumulator (f value, xs <> ys)
```